# Form redirect based on radio buttons and tick boxes?

Tags: forms, checkbox, radio-button, calculator

How do i create a form that will redirect the user to a different URL based on what they select?

The form will be very similar to https://www.dropbox.com/upgrade where you have 3 main radio buttons, monthly or annual radio buttons and a tick box for an add-on.

The form would also calculate the selections.

Comment: what did you try? can you post your code?

Comment: You don't mention how you wish to achieve this or the language e.g. php? Or do you need something to work client side? Note: you cannot nest forms, but you can use java to copy selections into hidden fields between forms. Personally I would do this in php and then build an appropriate response page with that.

Comment: Ah sorry, i did try and put some basic code together based on other posts on this site, but after a few attempts i couldnt get it working. I want to use HTML for the form but pass via PHP if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, the simplest way you can do this is by using an onclick event for the radio buttons which would update the form action property. A crude example would be:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="submitForm();" id="myForm" type="get">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio1" data-op="0" value="10" onclick="calcNow();" selected />Monthly&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="myRadio1" data-op="1" value="120" onclick="calcNow();" />Annually<br/>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio2" data-op="0" value="10" onclick="calcNow();" selected />Option A&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="myRadio2" data-op="1" value="20" onclick="calcNow();" />Option B<br/>
<input id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="10" onclick="calcNow();" />Add-on<br/>
<input id="myTotal" name="myTotal" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" /><br/>
<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="submitForm();" value="Continue" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pages = [[["page1.html","page2.html"],["page3.html","page4.html"]],[["page5.html","page6.html"],["page7.html","page8.html"]]];

function calcNow()
{
    var cb = document.getElementById("myCheckbox");
    var cost1 = getRadioValue("myRadio1");
    var cost2 = getRadioValue("myRadio2");
    var cost3 = cb.checked ? parseInt(cb.value) : 0;
    var costTotal = cost1 + cost2 + cost3;
    document.getElementById("myTotal").value = costTotal;

    var op1 = getRadioData("myRadio1", "op");
    var op2 = getRadioData("myRadio2", "op");
    var op3 = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;

    if (op1 != undefined && op2 != undefined && op3 != undefined)
    {
        return pages[op1][op2][op3];
    }
    return undefined;
}

function submitForm()
{
    var page = calcNow();
    if (page != undefined)
    {
        // ---- To popup ----
        //alert(page);
        // ---- To navigate ----
        location.href = page;
        // ---- To alter post ----
        //var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        //form.action = page;
        //form.submit();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please answer all questions.");
    }
}

function getRadioValue(name)
{
  var controls = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
      if (controls[i].checked) {
          return parseInt(controls[i].value);
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

function getRadioData(name, attribute)
{
  var controls = document.getElementsByName(name);
  for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
      if (controls[i].checked) {
          return parseInt(controls[i].dataset[attribute]);
      }
  }
  return undefined;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that this is quite basic html and javascript, so if you are having troubles with this you may need to get in touch with a web designer. This part is the easy bit!

Comment: Thanks Sav, what would i need to change to add further buttons and tick boxes. An example would be if a user selected radio 1, radio B, then the tick box, another would be radio 2, radio A and no tick box. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: The second part to the question is: How do I then redirect to a URL based on these values?

For example, if someone clicks monthly and option a it goes to pagea.html, if they click monthly with option b it goes to pageb.html etc etc...

Thanks again

Comment: The code has been updated to allow page selection. Note that as it has not been specified, i've added commented code to allow for opening the new page as a link, or updating the form to post to the new page with the selected parameters. Currently the selected page will just show in a popup; you can uncomment whichever version one you need. This code could be simplified with the use of jQuery if you are already using that library. Also, this page shouldn't be used for generating costing or invoicing based on values provided by this form, as it would be easily spoofable.

Comment: Sorry to be a further pain... the form doesnt redirect to the pages, it simply pops up with this image - http://i1225.photobucket.com/albums/ee398/76uk/pagepop.png

Comment: I had left the redirect code commented because you didn't specify if it was a standard page redirect or a form redirect. I've updated the code to perform the page redirect.

Comment: You're a star Sav! Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear it is working for you. If this has answered your question then please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Sav, what if the form was just 2 check boxes and a default / pre-selected / required item (div?)? I can't get the javascript working to remove the radio buttons, add a second check box and add a value on page visit of £1... Please help!

Comment: Do you mean 3 check boxes, where one of them is required and can't be unticked?

Comment: either that or 2 checkboxes and one pre-selected amount of £1

Comment: I guess the 3 checkboxes works better as we will be passing to one of 4 URLs. Can the main default checkbox be hidden?

Comment: Hi Sav, can you help please?

Comment: Hi doug, I've already posted quite a lot of code to get you started and see how all the controls work. If you have a specific issue then please provide the code that is causing an error. The code to add a checkbox is already in the code above. If you are struggling to add a checkbox then you are going to need to speak to an actual web designer.

Comment: Here's my code so far - http://jsfiddle.net/doug76/bh9CP/

My issue is that i can't get the checkboxes to work! I keep playing with the JS but nothing. I want the 'Default option' to be hidden and preselected on page load, and the 2 other options to be optional add-ons - not required.

Can you help me please...